# Need a sensible version-control scheme for shared library code

Tags: matlab, version-control, mercurial

Using Matlab for development and Mercurial for version-control, how do I properly version all code for each of my projects, when they share some common classes and functions?

My current scheme addresses this imperfectly; I have a repository for each project and a repository for the common library. This necessitates a manual manipulation protocol, including:

- Manually referencing the project name/version in the commit description for the library
- Manually updating the changeset for both the project and library, if reverting to a previous state

This has worked reasonably well so far, but does run the risk of human error in following the protocol and unintended consequences of a library modification on another project. The latter can be addressed with `hg update -r` on the library, but is error-prone since I have to remember to go back, as I move between projects.

Searching here (and elsewhere), I thought I had found salvation in sub-repository branches, only to discover the practice is basically frowned upon and considered a feature of last resort.

I then found that some folks eschew direct versioning *with* the project in favor of treating the library as a package for the build software to manage. Taking the library off the Matlab path, creating version clones and telling the builder which one to use, for any particular project, is a brilliant idea - except that I also use the Matlab interpreter to run/debug my code, as well as use the library in various scripts, so I need the library on the Matlab path - which means the builder will automatically pick up the library version that's on the path.

The only other scheme I can think of is to copy the library dependencies into the Project folder for revision control by the project repository. A change protocol would have to include copying the affected library class/function back to the library folder and typing an appropriate commit message. The trick here would be in manually updating project copies of library files, unless there's a Mercurial command to selectively pull from a foreign repo.

Does anybody have a better, more robust way to manage shared library code among projects in both  interpreter and build environments?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it. -- It's a fine line. I'm just putting this here to caution you.

Comment: Which release are you using? There's been a fair amount of functionality added over the last releases with respect to interfacing with source control software. See http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/source-control.html.

Comment: @Schorsch, thank you for the caution; I do understand I am potentially inviting opinion, so apologies for that, but I am also hoping there exists a known solution.

Comment: @am304, Yes, remiss of me; I am using Matlab 2014b and Mercurial 2.4.1 running under TortoiseHg 2.6.1, as part of FogCreek's Kiln Client and Tools. I shall check out the link you provided. Thanks.

Comment: @am304 Unfortunately the new functionality supports only Git and Subversion, not Mercurial.

Comment: Does Mercurial support the Microsoft Source Code Control Interface (MSSCCI)? I only have a limited understanding, but as far as I know it's like an API (which is supported by most source control software packages), which allows you to write your own interface.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand the question.  Why not just ignore the library with `.hgignore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who commented and to those who took the time to read my question. I am loathe to ask questions, since I never think my queries are so novel as to be previously un-asked. But in this case, I was finding it hard to come up with the right search terms/phrase; hence the less-than concise phrasing of my question.

I still don't know if there's a standard approach to managing software configuration for a project, when it includes non-project-specific dependencies, but the scheme I've decided to adopt is outlined below. I should say that the development framework I'm using is Matlab, which may well be argued isn't a terribly good framework for developing a GUI application, but it's the only one I have for now. Should I move to .Net, or some other framework, then maybe some of the issues I'm having would be much more readily resolved.

I decided the ability to version a project in its entirety took precedence and so I copied all of the project-agnostic dependencies (that is, functions and classes that I've developed) from a central library repo to a folder within the project repo.

It just means I have to be disciplined in managing the Matlab search path, as well as the protocol for copying changes made to these dependencies back to the central library - and for polling the library for any changes that originated from another project.

This doesn't seem elegant, but it does make me think more carefully about the functions and interfaces that I put into the library, which should be a good thing.